# stereo_image_proc : Assertion `left_.fx() == right_.fx()'

Tags: stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get stereo_image_proc running.

I have two externally triggered Prosilica GC655C cameras. The camera drivers are working, so I can retrieve single image views without any problem. However trying to view the disparity image with disparity viewer or stereo view with stereo viewer fails.

`rosrun image_view disparity_view image:=prosilica/disparity`

fails with the error:

`` stereo_image_proc: /tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-vision-opencv-1.4.3/debian/ros-diamondback-vision-opencv/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_opencv/image_geometry/src/stereo_camera_model.cpp:29: bool image_geometry::StereoCameraModel::fromCameraInfo(const sensor_msgs::CameraInfo&, const sensor_msgs::CameraInfo&): Assertion `left_.fx() == right_.fx()' failed. ``

for me it's very strange why the camera parameters `left_.fx()` and `right_.fx()` must be equal?! Since I use two cameras, (each camera calibrated as mono camera was working) the two parameters differ slightly.

Does someone has an idea why the parameters have to be equal?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11010/stereo_image_proc-:-assertion-%60left_.fx()-==-right_.fx()%27/) by [Daniel Eberli](https://answers.ros.org/users/940/daniel-eberli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2011-08-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

found  the solution by myself.

i did not read properly the comments about camera calibration. in

`rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py [..]`

i used `_approximate_sync:=True` instead of `--approximate 0.01`. Doing calibration properly will also make the `stereo_image_proc` work properly.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Eberli](https://answers.ros.org/users/940/daniel-eberli/) with karma: 91 on 2011-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3